# How to get the correct label when predicting in Keras using a folder structure?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generator

Since my dataset is a collection of images, I use a folder structure to organize the data:

```
/train
    /class1
        img.jpg
        img.jpg
        ...
    /class2
        ...
/validation
    /class1
        ...
    /class2
        ...
```

There are only two classes so I used the binary class mode like so:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Now, when using the `predict()` function, the output is obviously a numeric value between 0 and 1. However, I don't know which label belongs to which value (0 or 1). How do I get the true label (class1 or class2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the class names, just call:

```
generator.classes
```